# UIButton action(rx.tap) responds to different PublishSubjects with RxSwift

Tags: ios, iphone, data-binding, uibutton, rx-swift

I would like to bind different actions for a button in RxSwift. 
I have binding

```
registerButton.rx.tap
            .map { self.registerButton.isEnabled = false }
            .bind(to: viewModel.registrationPressed)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and wanna switch to

```
self.registerButton.rx.tap
        .map { self.registerButton.isEnabled = false }
        .bind(to: viewModel.registerPinPressed)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

with

```
let registrationPressed = PublishSubject<Void>()
let registerPinPressed = PublishSubject<Void>()
```

Is there any way to unbind the first binding?

EDIT:
It seems that unbinding is not possible, but thanx to Daniel T. I found the solution that works.

```
let tap = registerButton.rx.tap
            .map { _ in
                self.isFormProcessed
            }

        tap.filter { !$0 }
            .toVoid()
            .bind (to: viewModel.registrationPressed)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        tap.filter { $0 }
            .toVoid()
            .bind(to: viewModel.registerPinPressed)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: what is the criteria for which subject gets triggered?

Comment: @DanielT. if the first request has passed I wish to bind another action for the same button.

Comment: You disable the button after the first tap. There won't be a second one...

Comment: @DanielT. thanx, but I need to bind another action and remove the first one, not to disable.

Comment: Okay, because you should never change state inside a `map` like that. It leads to a world of heartache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is have the button taps alternate between two different streams. Here is one way of doing it. I expect there are a lot of others:

```
let tap = registerButton.rx.tap
    .map { 1 }
    .scan(0) { $0 + $1 }
    .map { $0 % 2 == 0 }

tap.filter { $0 }
    .bind(to: viewModel.registrationPressed)
    .disposed(by: bag)

tap.filter { !$0 }
    .bind(to: viewModel.registerPinPressed)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Here's a method that is more self-documenting:

```
enum WhichStream {
    case registration
    case pin
}

let tap = registerButton.rx.tap
    .scan(WhichStream.pin) { last, _ in
        switch last {
        case .pin:
            return .registration
        case .registration:
            return .pin
        }
    }

tap.filter { $0 == .registration }
    .bind(to: viewModel.registrationPressed)
    .disposed(by: bag)

tap.filter { $0 == .pin }
    .bind(to: viewModel.registerPinPressed)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

There's probably a better solution that doesn't involve PublishSubjects at all, but without knowing the context this is as far as I can go.

Comment: Looks promising, but I need to do the switch after the first action is processed correctly, this seems to switch right after the first tap if I am not mistaken.

Comment: The switch is on the first tap, but it switches *to* the registrationPressed on the first pass, so it's correct.